# Как wordpress используя custom post type, необходимо отображение шаблона записи в зависимости от категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создан произвольный тип записи (custom post type). Собственно сложность возникает в том что для 1 записи используются несколько категорий и в зависимости от того из какой категории мы просматриваем данную запись нам необходимо отображать соответствующий шаблон.
Сложность возникает когда у одной записи несколько категорий и wp выбирает первый шаблон... Как это решить?

Пробовал таким образом

```
function get_custom_single_template($single_template)
{
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'product') { // Тип записи
            $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'catalog'); // название таксономии
            if($terms && !is_wp_error( $terms )) {
                    //Make a foreach because $terms is an array but it supposed to be only one term
                    foreach($terms as $term){
                            $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template-'.$term->slug.'.php';
                    }
            }
     }
     return $single_template;
}

add_filter("single_template", "get_custom_single_template");
```

Comment: Что значит "в зависимости от того из какой категории мы просматриваем данную запись"? Это невозможно. Запрашивается запись, а "категория" - это просто доп поле у неё (на самом деле немого не так, но для простоты понимания логики можно считать что так)

Comment: Можно же назначить в acf  условие для категории, чтобы  отображались определенные поля. Соответственно если мы выбираем все категории, то у записи выводятся соответствующие поля. Но тут возникаем сложность, если записи задано несколько категорий, запись отображается с одним шаблоном(который wp выбрал). а хотелось бы реализовать, что если мы просматриваем запись в определенной категории, то выводится соответствующий шаблон. Но WP выбирает тот, который первый нашел

Comment: @SeVlad если записи присвоена 1 категория, то шаблон подгружается корректно, а необходимо при просмотре записи исходя из просматриваемой категории отображать соответствующий шаблон

Comment: Ещё раз: ты запрашиваешь запись. А рубрика (а не категория) - это всего лишь доп поле.  Запрашивать "из рубрики" не возможно физически. Можно лишь отслеживать реферер.

Comment: @SeVlad Понял, спасибо)